# Can Mavericks behave like Lion on multiple screens?

Tags: macos, display

I've switched to Mavericks and like the new features so far. But one thing bothers me - the new multi-screen behavior.

#### New in Mavericks

- Multiple status bars
- separated fullscreen modes

I don't like (need) a status bar on each screen simply because it reduces space and I have to click on the status bar to activate it, and I never use the fullscreen mode.

I have my browser opened on my small screen (MacBook) and all other applications on the big one.
When I click a link in Mail, Chrome always opens a new window instead of a new tab (the main reason I don't like it).

Sorry for all the extra stuff, here is my question:

**Can Mavericks behave like Lion on multiple screens?**

Is there anything like a third-party plugin or a hidden setting via the terminal?

Comment: Relevant or duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106541/mavericks-window-across-multiple-monitors/106544#106544

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second menubar problem, you can unset the last checkbox in Mission Control preferences panel.

To do this: System Preferences > Mission Control. Uncheck the fifth checkbox "Display have separate spaces"

[image: french screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

*Systems Preferences/Mission Control*
*Screens have distinct Spaces* (last item to uncheck) That should remove the status bar and act as usual. Not that I "translated" from my French configuration, so It may not be exactly the same words.